# Continuity of the minimal distance function

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $C\subset X$ a bounded, closed and convex set. The distance function
$$x \mapsto d(x,C)$$
is nonexpansive. Is the mapping
$$C\mapsto d(x,C)$$
continuous with respect to the Hausdorff distance?

Comment: How is $d(x,C)$ defined for an arbitrary Banach space?

Comment: @Math1000 $d(x,C)=\inf_{y\in C}\|x-y\|$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We can even show non-expansiveness, i.e.
$$|d(x, C) - d(x, D)| \le d_H(C, D)$$
for all non-empty bounded subsets $C, D$, where $d_H$ is the Hausdorff distance. Note that it suffices to show that
$$d(x, D) \le d(x, C) + d_H(C, D).$$
Note that, for every point $p \in C$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a point $q_{p,\varepsilon} \in D$ such that
$$\|p - q_{p, \varepsilon}\| < d(p, D) + \varepsilon \le \sup_{c \in C}d(c, D) + \varepsilon \le d_H(C, D) + \varepsilon.$$
As such,
$$d(x, D) \le \|x - q_{p, \varepsilon}\| \le \|x - p\| + \|p - q_{p, \varepsilon}\| < \|x - p\| + d_H(C, D) + \varepsilon.$$
As $p \in C$ is arbitrary, we may take the infimum with respect to $p \in C$ to get
$$d(x, D) \le d(x, C) + d_H(C, D) + \varepsilon.$$
As $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we get the result we need.